# Custom script echo -e parameter

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script for a school asignment. We are asked to do backups using the linux tools. I'm trying to make the experience better using parameters to let the user customize the backup. I want to use parameters with that in mind, and so I'm trying to see if the second parameter starts with -, knowing that if it starts with - it's another parameter, and so I want a different behaviour.

```
echo "$2" | grep "^-" > /dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
  #This works while the parameters are not -e, -E or -n
  echo $2
  echo "Input backup folder"
  read path
else
  path=$2
  shift
fi
```

So, the question is:
Do you know how can I bypass this problem? 
I have find that this works whenever the parameter are not -e, -E nor -n being that echo parameters. And so I've been trying to escape the content of the parameter, but I can't find the answer. 
I'm fine with whatever solution, being another way to test if the second parameter starts with -, or a way to escape the content.

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more idiomatic way to achieve the functionality you are aiming at is

```
case "$2" in
  (-*)
    echo "Set parameter '$2'"
    read -p "Input backup folder: " path
  ;;
  (*)
    path="$2"
    echo "Path: $path"
  ;;
esac
shift
```

but this is only part of the story... you should wrap this around a `while [ -n "$1" ]; do ...; done` loop and so on. But you probably already know this.

(Also, using `$path` for the backup folder works and is perfectly legal; variable names are case-sensitive and the shell won’t get confused, but perhaps human readers might be distracted by the fact that `$PATH` is a completely different thing.)

Answer (score 2):

Prefer `printf` to `echo`, as its behavior is better defined and more consistent across implementations.

```
if [[ $2 = -* ]]; then
    printf '%s\n'  "$2"
    echo "Input backup folder"
    read path
else
    path=$2
    shift
fi
```

However, you should look at the `getopt` command, which provides handling for options and their arguments.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the argument separator is a space, so keep in mind this test:

```
$ function test { echo "First Parameter:$1";echo "Second Parameter:$2";}
$ test alpha veta
First Parameter:alpha
Second Parameter:veta
```

If you need to pass alpha veta as one pararameter you need to use single quotes around them , or treat those parameters in your own way in your script based in your own criteria.

To test if a parameter starts with `-` you can get the first char using
`${1:0:1}` and you can then compare this to `"-"`.
Example:

```
$ function test { echo "First Parameter:$1";echo "Second Parameter:$2"; if [[ "${1:0:1}" == "-" ]];then echo "First Char is a dash";fi;}
$ test -alpha veta
First Parameter:-alpha
Second Parameter:veta
First Char is a dash
```

Update :
Your example could work and get not stuck to parameters like -e or -E if you modify the grep like this :

```
echo "$2" | grep -e "^-" > /dev/null
```

The `-e` grep switch tells to grep that what it follows is a pattern.

It is known that if -e option is not provided in grep this causes problems with patterns that start with dash, since grep can misunderstand those patterns as grep options.